# Aligning the logo with the input fields on ASP.NET MVC 4 using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, view

Im designing a website using Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET MVC4

And it’s supposed to be like this

---

[image: default1]

---

but it turned out to be like this

---

![default2][2]

---

I need to align the logo with the Username & Password fields and those fields should have space in between. Btw, I'm using the latest version of Twitter Bootstrap as my CSS. Thanks for helping out!

Also, these are my codes.

```
 <header class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/Logo-Sample.png")" alt="Image" id="logo" class="img-responsive"/>
                            <div class="pull-right">

                                <form class="navbar-form pull-right" role="form">

                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Username">
                             </div>

                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
                             </div>
                             <div class="checkbox">
                                 <label>
                                     <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                                 </label>
                             </div>
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>              
              </div>






    </header>
```

Update:

I've applied Ryan's suggestion the "float stuff" and the logo is now inlined with the input fields.

[image]

But the input field went upward instead of downward. Any suggestions for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Bootstrap's docs for Inline forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline). I believe this is exactly what you are looking for.

As a side note, check out [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation#forms-inline). Your code might look cleaner with it.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your logo and login sections are both block-level elements.  They need to be inline-block OR one of them needs to be floated left or right as appropriate.

Insofar as the space between elements for your login block... I'd do a css selector to match the header login input elements and add some margin-right to them.

Comment: Hello i got your idea of applying float to it. I floated the logo to the left and it went that way. Now my dilemma is that the input fields is not well aligned as wanted. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

HTML formatting is very finicky sometimes. However, open up the markup for the asp file and put a space between those input areas' tags or put one trailing after the word in the placeholder. For the being slightly too high, I forgot the word I am looking for, but its something a bit like a table, make them both in slots for that row. Look around for what Im attempting to say as I just completely forgot the term.
(if I remember Ill come back and edit this)

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. I already tried using row but it is still like that.